# Get Value from SharePoint list into a Checkbox in C#

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, c-sharp

I have a SharePoint list that contain column 'District' with some data in it. It contains 4 value, District 1, District 2, District 3 and District 4.

I want to grab that value 'District' in the SharePoint list items and put it in my ASP Form as a checkbox to eventually make a filter on a Grid View.

If anyone can help me with grabbing the value of SharePoint List items and turning it into checkbox, would really appreciate it.

Comment: Is data type of your `District` is **Choice**?? or single lines of text?

Comment: It is a single line of text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In case,** the `District` is a **single line of text**, try the below code

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("SiteURL"))
   {
     using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
      {
       SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];
       SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
       query.Query = "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='District'/></ViewFields></View>"; 
       SPListItemCollection Items = list.GetItems(query);
      // Bind Checkbox List
       foreach (SPListItem Item in Items)
          {
             //CheckBoxListID.Items.Add(item["District"]);
              CheckBoxListID.Items.Add(new ListItem(Item.Title));
          }
      }
}
```

**In case,** the `District` is your field is a **choice** field, Please check, [Retrieve a SharePoint Choice Field Value Using Server Object Model C#](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/20/retrieve-value-of-a-sharepoint-choice-field-in-c-visual-studio-2010/)

Comment: Thankyou for the answer but i got a little red line under the 'item' before the [District] in this line  CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.["District)"]));, what should i replace it with?

Comment: Could you try this **CheckBoxListID.Items.Add(item["District"]);** or **CheckBoxListID.Items.Add(new ListItem(Item.Title));**

Comment: Thank you so much sir, that works like a charm=))